# Does serde skip attribute actually skip an enum variant?

Tags: rust, serde, bincode

I have an enum like this one:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum E {
    A(i32),

    #[serde(skip)]
    B(bool),

    C(char),
    D(Vec<i32>),
}
```

Then I try to do the following with [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) crate:

```
fn main() {
    let data = E::C('A');
    let encoded = bincode::serialize(&data).unwrap();
    let decoded = bincode::deserialize::<E>(&encoded).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", decoded);
}
```

However this panics with the following message:

> ```
> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "failed to fill whole buffer" })', src/main.rs:16:19
> ```

I noticed, that everything works if one of the following :

1. I remove `#[serde(skip)]` attribute
2. I remove tuples from variants

Also I understand that bincode somehow ignores `#[serde(skip)]` and tries to deserialize `encoded` as `E::D(Vec<i32>)`. If I change `Vec<i32>` to `char` it will work, but `decoded` will be `E::D('A')` (instead of `E::C('A')`).

Do I miss something or is it a bug in bincode crate?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `bincode`.

Comment: This seems to be this issue: https://github.com/servo/bincode/issues/184

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It is sad news; bincode has already reached 1.0.0 but has such an annoying bug. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like at the moment, skipping fields with `serde` doesn't work well on formats that are not self-describing like `bincode`. There are several open issues about this:

- [`skip_serializing_if` is a footgun](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1732) on `serde`'s GitHub repository.
- [`skip_deserializing` variant attribute has confusing behavior](https://github.com/servo/bincode/issues/184) on `bincode`'s GitHub repository.